# How can i pull xcom value from Airflow sensor?

Tags: python, airflow

**Main Problem:** I am trying to create a BigQuery Table, if not exists.

**Approach:** Using BigQueryTableSensor to check if table exists, and based on the return value, creates or not a new table using BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator.

**Problem:** I'm not able to get the return value of BigQueryTableSensor sensor using xcom. As we know, the poke method need to return a boolean value.

This is how i created my task:

```py
check_if_table_exists = BigQueryTableSensor(
        task_id='check_if_table_exists',
        project_id='my_project',
        dataset_id='my_dataset',
        table_id='my_table',
        bigquery_conn_id='bigquery_default',
        timeout=120,
        do_xcom_push=True,
    )

# Output: INFO - Success criteria met. Exiting.

get_results = BashOperator(
        task_id='get_results',
        bash_command="echo {{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='check_if_table_exists') }}"
    )

# Output: INFO - Running command: echo None
```

Looking at Airflow interface, i checked that BigQueryTableSensor didn't pushed nothing :(

[image]

**Question:**

- Is there a way that i can get the return value of my sensor?
- Is there a better approach to solve my main problem? Maybe using BigQueryOperator and a sql query like "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS".

Comment: probably you can change the answer "Yes it's possible" as the accepted answer, I think it would help better people to find the answer to the title of the question.
(The current accepted answer is specific to BigQueryTableSensor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the use case for Sensors.
Sensors makes the workflow to wait for something to happen. In your case `BigQueryTableSensor` will wait until the table created by some other process and only then will continue to downstream task.

What you are looking for is either:

1. Using  `BigQueryCheckOperator` to run a query that return boolean value (True if table exist, False otherwise) then you will be able to pull the boolean value from XCOM in your `BashOperator`.
2. Branch operator (like: `BranchSQLOperator`) where the workflow
   branch based on the result of SQL query that checks if the table
   exist. In that option there is no need to use XCOM.

Answer (score 7):

Yes it's possible, I made it work like this:

```
class MyCustomSensor(BaseSensorOperator):

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self,
                 *args,
                 **kwargs):
        super(MyCustomSensor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def poke(self, context):
        application_id = context['ti'].xcom_pull(key='application_id')
        print("We found " + application_id)
        return True
```

Here is a full DAG example:

```
import os
import sys
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG, settings
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.sensors.base_sensor_operator import BaseSensorOperator
from airflow.utils.decorators import apply_defaults


dag = DAG('my_dag_name',
          description='DAG ',
          schedule_interval=None,
          start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 7),
          tags=["samples"],
          catchup=False)

class MyCustomSensor(BaseSensorOperator):

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self,
                 *args,
                 **kwargs):
        super(MyCustomSensor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def poke(self, context):
        application_id = context['ti'].xcom_pull(key='application_id')
        print("We found " + application_id)
        return True


def launch_spark_job(**kwargs):
    application_id = "application_1613995447156_11473"
    kwargs['ti'].xcom_push(key='application_id', value=application_id)


launch_spark_job_op = PythonOperator(task_id='test_python',
                                     python_callable=launch_spark_job,
                                     provide_context=True,
                                     dag=dag)

wait_spark_job_sens = MyCustomSensor(task_id='wait_spark_job',
                                     dag=dag,
                                     mode="reschedule")

launch_spark_job_op >> wait_spark_job_sens
```

Comment: What a champ !!

Answer (score 3):

I know the other answers are good, but I just want to share another solution in case it may help someone else. I know this solution works for Apache Airflow 2.x.x, not sure about 1.x.x though.

You can use jinja templates and the "op_kwargs" parameter in a PythonSensor (look at [this](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/sensors/python/index.html)), so a python script can read those values at least.

Example:

```
waiting_sjs_job = PythonSensor(
    task_id="waiting_job",
    python_callable=waiting_job,
    mode="reschedule",
    poke_interval=60,
    timeout=60*60*2,
    op_kwargs={'sjs_url': '{{ ti.xcom_pull(key="sjs_url") }}', 'job_id': '{{ ti.xcom_pull(key="job_id") }}'},
)

def waiting_job(sjs_url, job_id):
   # those lines commented below are equivalent to the parameters passed to this function
   # ti = kwargs['ti']
   # sjs_url = ti.xcom_pull(key="sjs_url")
   # job_id = ti.xcom_pull(key="job_id")
   r = requests.get( sjs_url + '/jobs/' + job_id)
   json_data = r.json()
   if json_data['status'] != 'RUNNING':
      return True
   r.raise_for_status()
   return False
```

Comment: what does `sjs_url` mean or do in this example?

Comment: @nate sorry for a long time to reply, "sjs_url" is just part of the example, it represents a parameter in the "waiting_job" function that is automatically converted to its value given the jinja template `'sjs_url': '{{ ti.xcom_pull(key="sjs_url") }}'`