# Using XComs in Airflow Sensors

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a data pipeline which consists of several Sensors that look for a file in Azure Blob Storage. When one of the sensors is triggered, a Spark job needs to be executed. I am simply ingesting the data in these files to MySQL database tables. The Spark job remains pretty much the same, only the table that the data is ingested to will change.

I was hoping to do this using a single SparkSubmitOperator by making use of XComs. I was thinking that I could save the name of the file that triggered the sensor to a XCom and decide which table I should ingest the data to using it.

I understand how a XCom can be pushed using PythonOperator and BashOperator, but is it not possible to do this with Sensors?

I am using the WasbBlobSensor here and this is what the code for that looks like,

```
blob_sensors = [
    WasbBlobSensor(
        task_id=blob.split('.')[0] + "_sensor",
        wasb_conn_id="wasb_default",
        container_name=blob_container,
        blob_name=blob,
        poke_interval=60,
        timeout=120,
        dag=dag) for blob in blob_names]
```

How can I push the name of the blob to a XCom using this Sensor? If it is not possible, is there any other solutions for my workflow?

I have referred the answer given here as well, but I do not know how relevant it is,
[How can i pull xcom value from Airflow sensor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67186944/how-can-i-pull-xcom-value-from-airflow-sensor)

This is a sample of what my DAG would look like,

[image]

Comment: Sensor verify that something exist / happened. So if you know what you want to verify (e.g the action of the sensor) how does it make sense to push it to xcom? You already know it. In your example you are waiting for a file so you are providing the file path. You already have the path so why do you need the sensor to push it to xcom?

Comment: Because I want to use the same Spark job, regardless of which sensor is triggered. Within the Spark job, I am writing data to a database. The table that I will be writing to will depend on the name of the file. So, if I can know what that file is, I can do it this way. Otherwise, I would have to have multiple Spark jobs (the same one, pretty much) after each sensor.

Comment: I have added an image of what my DAG would look like.